# nvme m.2 SSD stopped booting Windows 10 after 1 year of working fine. How to get Windows to boot again without reinstalling?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, smart, nvme

For background, I did not update any software in the recent days. I did not have any power outages. I did not make any changes to my computer. I didn't update Windows and had windows updates turned off for over a week. The last thing I did before my computer ran into this issue was I was using google and youtube.

When I turned on my computer, I was shown the login screen but when I tried to click on anything to type in my password, nothing would click so I decided to manually power off my computer then turn it back on. When I turned it back on, I was sent to BIOS.

My BIOS detects my Samsung 980 Pro NVMe M.2 SSD so I doubt it's hardware failure. I tried to reset my BIOS. I made a bootable flash drive with windows 10 iso and used v1703 since 1709 was giving me access denied issues when I tried to do bootrec /fixboot. I tried to created the partition scheme to be GPT and MBR but each time I could not get the Windows Startup repair to work without it telling me that it can't fix my issue. I tried typing in the command prompt in the windows flash drive boot up:

```
bootrec /fixmbr

The operation completed successfully.

bootrec /fixboot

The operation completed successfully.

bootrec /rebuildbcd

Total identified Windows installations: 1

[1] C:\Windows

Add installation to boot list? Yes(Y)/No(N)/All(A)

Cannot create a file when that file already exists
```

and it didn't fix the issue. It told me that I can't install Windows when it's already installed. I don't have any system images to restore to.

I tried to use diskpart and selecting the disk partition with windows on it "active" but I got the error that my selected disk not a fixed mbr disk. My disk has an astrick under GPT.

I don't know what else to try to get my SSD to boot up windows again. Yesterday it works fine and today it can't boot windows off my SSD like it always did for a year. I didn't change anything for a while on my computer that I could even imagine would have impacted this.

I can't run chkdsk C: /f either because the disk is write protected but there were issues found

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the SMART attributes of the disk. If you don't already have such a product, you may use [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).

Comment: Are you typing to get your existing install to boot or reinstall Windows? Because if you have, “created the partition scheme to be GPT and MBR”, that sounds like you formatted your disk. All evidence points to a hardware failure directly associated with the SSD.

Comment: @Ramhound I was talking about formatting the flash drive with the Windows installation iso on it to try to see if the errors would go away when trying to run command prompt. I'm trying to get my existing install to boot Windows again how it was before.

Comment: If you’re creating partition on your bootable media you’re creating the bootable memory improperly. Windows was installed in Legacy Mode or UEFI?

Comment: I used Rufus to create the bootable flash drive and I have to choose GPT or MBR for partition scheme. It was installed with UEFI.

Comment: I now used powerISO to recreate the bootable media and it was able to install windows on a new SSD but I can't access the old drive because it is write protected. @harrymc I can't run any scans or diagnostics besides what chkdsk will tell me since it's all write-protected.

Comment: @harrymc Found the data. Added it to the post. SMART not supported to view the 980 pro ssd on speccy

Comment: Do you still see your files on the disk? If yes, I suggest you first do a backup.

Comment: These are not the raw SMART attributes.

Comment: yeah they are, nvme smart. firmware switched drive to read-only mode. RAW value 9 so bit 0 and bit 3 set. this may be due to known but, see https://www.tomshardware.com/news/samsung-980-pro-ssd-failures-firmware-update.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen That probably is the issue. Going to RMA after backing up my drive.

Comment: @fpiette Yep, going to copy all the partitions onto an external drive then RMA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Firmware bug?

It is possible the drive has fallen victim to known bug, see https://www.tomshardware.com/news/samsung-980-pro-ssd-failures-firmware-update.

## SMART:

[image]

RAW value for critical warning is 9. This means bit 0 and 3 set. We can 'decode' (see https://nvmexpress.org/specifications/):

**00: If set to ‘1’, then the available spare space has fallen below the threshold.**

01: If set to ‘1’, then a temperature is above an over temperature threshold or below an under temperature
threshold.

02: If set to ‘1’, then the NVM subsystem reliability has been degraded due to significant media related errors or any internal error that degrades NVM subsystem reliability.

**03: If set to ‘1’, then the media has been placed in read only mode.**

04: If set to ‘1’, then the volatile memory backup device has failed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If a flash device becomes read-only there is a strong chance that you exhausted the usable pool of writable blocks. Good firmware blocks write access to the device, a bad one will allow neither writes nor reads.

To reinstall your windows you should duplicate your drive to a new one and try if this copy is working in your computer.

If you are interested in further error examination, install a linux distribution like the "Knoppix DVD" on a pendrive. The Knoppix DVD comes with two helpful tools, smartmontools and ddrescue.

You can use smartmontools to see if your Samsung device supports SMART information and you can create a smartmontools log file:

https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10910

To find the correct device, use the `lsbk` command.

Save the log file to another pendrive that you have formated before with the FAT32 file system. Running Windows on a different machine, install Notepad++ and use Notepad++ to change the line endings of the log file from Unix to windows format.

Post the log file here.

When running Knoppix, you can use the `ddrescue` command to duplicate your NVME device into a file on a harddrive.
Afterwards you replace the NVME device by a new one and copy the freshly generated image of your broken NVME device onto the new NVME device.

Shut the machine down, remove the pendrives and restart the machine to see if that works.